# sudo apt-get install python-dev mirror error

Tags: software-installation, apt

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
python-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 920 B of archives.
After this operation, 25.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main python-dev all 2.7.3-4+deb7u1
Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/python-defaults/python-dev_2.7.3-4+deb7u1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'mirrordirector.raspbian.org'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I try to install spi but i see these mirrordirector error. How can i solve?

Comment: The error does say temporary issue resolving host so my first thought is to wait a few hours.

Comment: The error says "maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?" Did you try any of these?

Comment: Have you ever been able to run apt-get update or upgrade? Are you connected to the internet? Can you ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: this is the answer : 'run apt-get update
-bash: run: command not found'

Answer (score 1):

```
dig mirrordirector.raspbian.org
```

will let you know your dns is working

```
sudo nice apt-get update
```

Will make sure you have the correct urls

```
sudo nice apt-get upgrade
```

Will make sure you have the latest versions